# Why can't I reference this class from another app in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, import

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have two applications in my project -- common and mainsite .  In common, I have a file "model_utils.py" at the root of my application (right next to models.py).  It contains this code

```
class RawCol(Expression):

    def __init__(self, model, field_name):
        field = model._meta.get_field(field_name)
        self.table = model._meta.db_table
        self.column = field.column
        super().__init__(output_field=CharField())

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        sql = f'"{self.table}"."{self.column}"'
        return sql, []
```

How do I reference this class from my other application, "mainsite"?  I put this at the top of one of my files in mainsite ..

```
from common import RawCol
```

but when I run some tests, I get this error ...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RawCol' from 'common' (/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainsite_project/common/__init__.py)
```

**Edit:** Project structure at the top level directories looks like ...

```
+ common
+ mainsite
+ mainsite_project
+ manage.py
+ templates
+ venv
```

Comment: Can you share your project structure ?

Comment: Hi, Edited my quesiton with teh top level structure.  Is that what you wanted me to provide?

Comment: It seems a problem of circular import. You must be importing something from `mainsite` to this application. Can you please post your folder structure and parts o code where you are importing from `mainsite`?

Comment: I usually do something like from Project_name.apps.app_name.model_utils import RawCol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `from common.model_utils import RawCol`

instead of `from common import RawCol`

You always need to specify the exact .py file (without the .py ending) to import from.

If it still doesn't work, it can be a circular import problem.

If you try to import something from mainsite.model into common.model_utils and the other way around, you are creating an impossible import loop.

You can fix this by creating a seperate file like common/dependent_model.py and putting only the RawCol() class in there without any import from mainsite. Like this, the both files are not importing from each other (which doesn't work).